# Which is more preferable? Dispatch the response of a promise or dispatch an action stating a promise needs to be triggered?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Here are two code samples:

```
onClick() { // click-handler of a button
  axios.get(someUrl)
    .then(response => {
      // setData is a fn dispatching an action-creator passed through react-redux's connect()
      setData(response.data);
    });
}
```

or

```
// buttonClicked is also a fn dispatching an action-creator
// Difference being the middle-ware handles the entire async process
<button onClick={this.buttonClicked}>Click me</button>
```

The latter method will use Axios in some middleware, and then dispatch another action which will set the response data in the store.

So this means that the first approach will only dispatch one action, while the second approach will dispatch two actions.

Both ways obviously seem to work, but I would like to know what the best way would be. Is there a downside to either approach?

Comment: How did you get on with the two answers below, gjvatsalya?

Answer (score 1):

### Disclaimer: This is an opinionated answer, and somewhat rambly.

The thing about promises is that they work the way a human being would think of a promise. So use them like that in your program.  Typically IMO you should only use Promises when you know that an event would occur in the normal course of your program workflow, or when you are promising a result.

So for example if you ask for a socket connection, I promise to give one to you whenever I am able to, you don't have to wait for me, just go on and do your thing, as soon as I have done everything needed to get that back to you I will hand it to you; and you can move on in your workflow from the point that needs it. For example, (pseudo code):

```
   var Socket = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
         resolve(do_something_to_get_a_socket());
   });

   Socket.then(authenticate()).then(sendData());
```

etc.

Sticking a promise to an event handler like `onClick` should be a promise to do something for the user — use it in your code to create threads that will do the heavy lifting of complex processing, while the user is still able to interact with the interface.

For example, in a game a click could fire a dart and you promise that it will animate on the screen (and even if that glitches) you still promise that it will hit the target etc, but the user doesn't have to wait for the promise to be fulfilled to fire another dart.

So use Promises to make your program more readable by you and other coders, and use it to make workflow of your program more realistic to your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

I heavily recommend something like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-api-middleware

This middleware (or others like it) contain quite a few features you would most likely have to write yourself if you were to implement this with just axios in a callback. For example, it will automatically dispatch request, success, and failure actions based on the AJAX call's result.

When dispatching this action using the middleware, many things are taken care of for you.

```
{
  [CALL_API]: {
    endpoint: "http://example-api.com/endpoint",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { ... },
    types: [
      "GET_X_REQUEST", "GET_X_SUCCESS", "GET_X_FAILURE"
    ]
  }
}
```

Something like this will automatically fire a "GET_X_REQUEST" action when it begins to load. Then a success or failure action (with appropriate data or error objects attached as a payload) when the AJAX call completes or fails.

Or any similar middleware where Redux ends up handling the entire async process.